# Odd Formed Diophatine Equation Help

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am relatively new at solving these kind of equation and was wondering if someone can help with a step by step for an odd formed Diophantine equation. The particular equation I am trying to solve is $-x^2 -2xy + 44y = 43$.

The integer solutions are not in general form but are

$${y = -286, x = 23}$$
$${y = -286, x = 549}$$
$${y = -46, x = 39}$$
$${y = -46, x = 53}$$
$${y = 2, x = 5}$$
$${y = 2, x = -9}$$
$${y = 242, x = -505}$$
$${y = 242, x = 21}$$

Comment: I get the list of solutions to be $$\{(23, -286), (53, -46), (39, -46), (549, -286),\\(21, 242), \color{#C00}{(-9, 2)}, \color{#C00}{(5, 2)}, (-505, 242)\}$$

Comment: My bad, flipped the sign on the 2 value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The equation is equivalent to
$$
(x+2y+22)(22-x)=17\cdot31
$$

Comment: Mathematica: `{#,(43+#^2)/(44-2#)}&/@(22-Flatten[Outer[Times,{1,-1},{1,17},{1,31}]])`

Comment: Thanks, question though is there a way to solve this not using the prime factorization but rather with just modulo math?

Comment: Good luck with that since $22-x$ must divide $527$. If that is really what you want, you might want to add that requirement to your question.

Comment: I just was wondering as if the numbers get larger the prime factorization is hard to get. Thanks for pointing me in that direction though.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a quadratic, the quadratic formula is your friend.  Write it as 
$$x^2+2xy+43-44y=0\\x=\frac 12\left(-{2y}\pm\sqrt{4y^2-172+176y}\right)\\
=\frac 12\left(-{2y}\pm\sqrt{(2y+44)^2-1764}\right)$$
and you need to look for $y$s that will make the square root an integer.  If you define $z=2y+44$ and require $z$ to be even you are looking at $$z^2-42^2=w^2\\(z+w)(z-w)=42^2$$ and look at the factorizations of $42^2$ into even numbers.